# tidyverse error : This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Good afternoon ,

Under R , i installed the tidyverse package :

```
dput( data_reel)
structure(list(X19910108 = c("19910109", "19910104", "19910104", 
"19910111", "19910104", "19910111"), X126 = c("X266", "B7", "T133", 
"J34", "T218", "X249"), TVGUIDE = c("TVGUIDE", "MODMAT", "MASSEY", 
"KMART", "MASSEY", "ROSES"), X25503 = c(25503L, 47201L, 39039L, 
37351L, 38039L, 35751L), YES = c("YES", "YES", "YES", "NO", "YES", 
"NO"), KEY = c("KEY", "KEY", "KEY", "KEY", "KEY", "KEY"), YES.1 = c("YES", 
"YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"), BENTON = c("BENTON", "BENTON", 
"BENTON", "BENTON", "BENTON", "BENTON"), GALLATIN = c("GALLATIN", 
"GALLATIN", "GALLATIN", "GALLATIN", "GALLATIN", "GALLATIN"), 
    UNCOATED = c("UNCOATED", "UNCOATED", "UNCOATED", "UNCOATED", 
    "UNCOATED", "COATED"), UNCOATED.1 = c("UNCOATED", "COATED", 
    "UNCOATED", "COATED", "UNCOATED", "COATED"), NO = c("NO", 
    "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO"), LINE = c("LINE", "LINE", "LINE", 
    "LINE", "LINE", "LINE"), YES.2 = c("YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", 
    "YES", "YES"), Motter94 = c("Motter94", "WoodHoe70", "WoodHoe70", 
    "WoodHoe70", "WoodHoe70", "Motter94"), X821 = c(821L, 815L, 
    816L, 816L, 816L, 827L), X2 = c(2, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2), TABLOID = c("TABLOID", 
    "CATALOG", "CATALOG", "TABLOID", "CATALOG", "TABLOID"), NorthUS = c("NorthUS", 
    "NorthUS", "NorthUS", NA, "NorthUS", "CANADIAN"), X1911 = c(NA, 
    NA, 1910L, 1910L, 1910L, 1911L), X55 = c(55, 62, 52, 50, 
    50, 50), X46 = c(46L, 40L, 40L, 46L, 40L, 46L), X0.2 = c("0.3", 
    "0.433", "0.3", "0.3", "0.267", "0.3"), X17 = c(15, 16, 16, 
    17, 16.8, 16.5), X78 = c(80L, 80L, 75L, 80L, 76L, 75L), X0.75 = c(0.75, 
    NA, 0.3125, 0.75, 0.4375, 0.75), X20 = c(20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    28L, 30L), X13.1 = c(6.6, 6.5, 5.6, 0, 8.6, 0), X1700 = c(1900L, 
    1850L, 1467L, 2100L, 1467L, 2600L), X50.5 = c(54.9, 53.8, 
    55.6, 57.5, 53.8, 62.5), X36.4 = c(38.5, 39.8, 38.8, 42.5, 
    37.6, 37.5), X0 = c(0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 6), X0.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), X2.5 = c(2.5, 2.8, 2.5, 2.3, 2.5, 2.5), X1 = c(0.7, 
    0.9, 1.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6), X34 = c(34, 40, 40, 35, 40, 30), 
    X40 = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), X105 = c(105, 103.87, 
    108.06, 106.67, 103.87, 106.67), X100 = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L), band = c("noband", "noband", "noband", 
    "noband", "noband", "noband")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

When i try to re-order the data features based on their type , I get the following error :

```
data_reel %>% select(where(is.numeric), where(is.character))
Error: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.
i Contact the package author and suggest using `eval_select()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I tried to update tidyselect ( version 1.1.1 ) , I have the following error :

```
update.packages("tidyselect")
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

Another try :

```
install.packages("tidyselect")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mouad/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tidyselect’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
```

Thank you for help !

Comment: Does `install.packages("tidyselect")` work?

Comment: No it doesn´t work , i updated the post !

Comment: I tried options(repos='cran.rstudio.com/') and now i can install packages

Comment: Could someone help !

Comment: Do you have internet? The `cannot open URL` messages suggest the website is blocked somehow?

Comment: Yes there is no pb in my internet